# anonymous type and multiple properties

Tags: linq

I have this error: An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name. Whether this can be resolved with alias ie, whether an alias exists in LINQ

```
var device_query = from d in DevicesEntities.device
             join dt in DevicesEntities.devicetype on d.DeviceTypeId equals dt.Id
             join l in DevicesEntities.location on d.Id equals l.DeviceId
             join loc in DevicesEntities.locationname on l.LocationNameId equals loc.Id
                           where l.DeviceId == d.Id
                           select new {
                               d.Id,
                               d.DeviceTypeId,
                               d.SerialNumber,
                               d.FirmwareRev,
                               d.ProductionDate,
                               d.ReparationDate,
                               d.DateOfLastCalibration,
                               d.DateOfLastCalibrationCheck,
                               d.CalCertificateFile,
                               d.Notes,
                               d.TestReportFile,
                               d.WarrantyFile,
                               d.CertificateOfOriginFile,
                               d.QCPermissionFile,
                               d.Reserved,
                               d.ReservedFor,
                               d.Weight,
                               d.Price,
                               d.SoftwareVersion,
                               dt.Name,
                               dt.ArticleNumber,
                               dt.Type,
                               l.StartDate, //AS LastStartDate,
                               l.LocationNameId,
                               loc.Name //in this line I have problem
                           };
```

Comment: @ognjenb - I am not sure what you are asking. It is true that an anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name. But how are you creating instances of that type? Are you asking if LINQ will automatically create an alias? If you have some sample code it would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to provide alternative names for the duplicate properties. For example:

```
select new {
   // ... other properties here ...
   dt.Name,
   dt.ArticleNumber,
   dt.Type,
   LastStartDate = l.StartDate,
   l.LocationNameId,
   CurrentLocation = loc.Name
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a confligt on "Name"
You are mapping both dt.Name and loc.Name, both which the compiler tries to set to the "Name" property of the anon type.

change one of them to e.g. LoationName = loc.Name.

HTH

[edit]
Way too late to hit submit :-)